# Refresh DataGrid from ViewModel fils MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have  MainWindow and Window Add , ViewModel and ViewModelADD..l'addition of new Customer is correct in database, but the refresh of DataGrid no ! and when i finish l'addition , the Window ADD doesn't close !

ViewModel:

```
private static ViewModel1 instance = new ViewModel1();
public static ViewModel1 Instance { get { return instance; } }

private void add(object obj)
{
    Add addView = new Add();
    addView.DataContext = new ViewModelADD(loadDataBinding);
    addView.Show();
}

private ObservableCollection<Custmor> _loadDataBinding;

public ObservableCollection<Custmor> loadDataBinding
{
    get
    {
        return _loadDataBinding;
    }

    set
    {
        _loadDataBinding = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("loadDataBinding");
    }
}
```

ViewModelADD:

```
public ViewModelADD(ObservableCollection<Custmor> loadDataBinding)
{
    CustomerToAddObject = new Custmor();

    addCustomer1 = new RelayCommand(ADDFunction);
}


private ICommand addCustomer1;
public ICommand AddCustomer1
{
    get { return addCustomer1; }
}


private void ADDFunction(object obj)
{
    using (Test1Entities context = new Test1Entities())
    {
        context.Custmor.Add(customerToAddObject);
        context.SaveChanges();

    }

    ViewModel1.Instance.loadDataBinding.Add(customerToAddObject);

    if (addView != null)
        addView.Close();
    CustomerToAddObject = new Custmor();
```

I try to refresh the DataGrid with : 
`ViewModel1.Instance.loadDataBinding.Add(customerToAddObject);`

and to try close the Window ADD, I try:

```
if (addView != null)
    addView.Close();
CustomerToAddObject = new Custmor();
```

but always the problem still: the dataGrid doesn't refresh and the Window ADD doesn't close..and the save in database is correct

Comment: I can guess that the question is too broad? "Help me write my application for me" is not a question.
You need to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the object to the collection that you inject the `ViewModelADD` with:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<Custmor> _loadDataBinding;
public ViewModelADD(ObservableCollection<Custmor> loadDataBinding)
{
    CustomerToAddObject = new Custmor();
    addCustomer1 = new RelayCommand(ADDFunction);
    _loadDataBinding = loadDataBinding;   
}

...


private void ADDFunction(object obj)
{
    using (Test1Entities context = new Test1Entities())
    {
        context.Custmor.Add(customerToAddObject);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    _loadDataBinding.Add(customerToAddObject);
    ...
}
```

And since you open the window from within your view model you might as well also inject the window:

```
private readonly Window _window;
private readonly ObservableCollection<Custmor> _loadDataBinding;
public ViewModelADD(Window window, ObservableCollection<Custmor> loadDataBinding)
{
    CustomerToAddObject = new Custmor();
    addCustomer1 = new RelayCommand(ADDFunction);
    _window = window;
    _loadDataBinding = loadDataBinding;   
}
...


private void ADDFunction(object obj)
{
    using (Test1Entities context = new Test1Entities())
    {
        context.Custmor.Add(customerToAddObject);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    _loadDataBinding.Add(customerToAddObject);
    _window.Close();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I modify first part like the your first answer, the DataGrid refresh now.
but the second part to close the Window ADD, i have an error..the name 'window' does no exist in the current context

Comment: Look at my answer again. The _window field is defined on the first line of the second code snippet. You pass a reference to the window when you create the view model in the add() method: addView.DataContext = new ViewModelADD(addView, loadDataBinding);

Comment: oh sorry I don't  concentrated..
Yes! It works now!
You are genius .;Thanks a lot!
thanks again